# Python script for word count execution

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, python-os

I have a folder "A" and many files within it ( say 100 ). I want to open the all these files(all are text files) and count the number of times the word "virtual memory" is present in all of them [Either the total sum or the number of times present in each file]
I tried something like this but not able to achieve the same.

```
path = 'MY_PATH'

count=0
filecount=0
files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
        print(files)
        for fileList in files:
            with open(fileList, "r") as f:
                # text = f.read()
                # print(len(text))
                print('OPENING FILE: ',f)
                for word in f:
                    #print(word)
                    if(word == 'virtual memory'):
                        print('WORD FOUND')
                        count+=1

print("COUNT : ", count)
```

Is there any quick script which I could use to execute the above query or some corrections I need to make? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using, say, ``grep``? Note that files are iterated *linewise*, so ``for word in f:`` is a misnomer - it should be ``for line in f:``, which should tell you that the nested if does not do what you think it does.

Comment: could the word virtual memory ever be split? 
I mean could `virtual` be on the end of one line and `memory` on the beginning of the next one?

If yes would you have to count such occurences.

If yes, then a slight modification of @alpha s code might do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `file.count` to count the number of a phrase in a `txt` file. Here a simple implementation how you can do this:

```
import os
path = 'MY_PATH'
count= 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        num=0
        with open(os.path.join(root, file),"r") as f:
            f_reader =f.read()
            team  = 'virtual memory'
            num = f_reader.count(team)
        count+=num
        print('OPENING FILE: ',file, ' - Count:', num)
print("COUNT : ", count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the list of files easily with is module like this:

```
listfiles = os.listdir('path/to/files/')
```

Then you can loop on this list and read the whole file without any loop like this:

```
count = [ ]
for file in listfiles:
    with open(file) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        count.append(sum(lines == 'virtual memory')
```

In this way the list *count* contains the occurrences of the string 'virtual memory' per each file.

The loop that you are doing with `for word in f` is a loop on the lines instead. When you open a file you iterate on its lines.

Answer (score 0):

Your script failed because the `word` is actually a **line**. The following can work:

```
with open(fileList, "r") as f:
    for sentence in f:
        count += sentence.count('virtual memory')
```

Comment: it's not really a sentence it's more a line, no?

A sentence could be spread over multiple lines

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        files.append(os.path.join(r, file))
# print(files)

# moving this for loop outside
# previously you were visiting each file more than once
for fileList in files:
    with open(fileList, "r") as f:
        print('OPENING FILE: ',f)
        lines = []
        for line in f:
            lines.extend(line.strip().split(" "))
        for idx in range(len(lines)-1):
            if lines[idx] == 'virtual' and lines[idx+1] == 'memory':
                count += 1

print("COUNT : ", count)
```